# Implement generic interface in a generic abstract class

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, abstract

Interface-

```
interface Service<T>
{
    void foo(T t);
}
```

I want to create an *abstract* class that implements the `Service` interface. I don't want to provide the implementation for `T` i.e. *generic*. That I will do in another child class of the *abstract* class.
How should I declare an *abstract* class with generic in it?

```
abstract class AbstractService implements Service<T>
```

is not cool with java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
abstract class AbstractService<T> implements Service<T>
```